# In angular-google-maps, how do I show ONLY my custom tiles?

Tags: angular-google-maps

I'm able to get my custom tiles to display, but the browser is also loading Google's standard map tiles underneath them.  This slows down performance and makes the map look weird if the user pans to the edges.  Any idea how to prevent the normal map layer?

[Demo](http://www.rslc.us/quartermaester/)

Comment: I've opened up a GitHub issue, to see if this requires an enhancement or not.  https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/1919

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I wound up avoiding the `ui-gmap-map-type` directive, even though I retained the parent [`ui-gmap-google-map`](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/google-map).  Instead, I waited for the `google.maps` & `$scope.map.control` objects to load, then I used the [`mapTypes.set()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image) method to point to my own set of image tiles.

**index.html**

```
<ui-gmap-google-map control='map.control'>
  <!-- marker & polygon directives -->
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

**controller.js**

```
$scope.map = {
  control: {}
};

uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function(maps) {
    var moonMapType = new maps.ImageMapType({
      getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
          var normalizedCoord = getNormalizedCoord(coord, zoom);
          if (!normalizedCoord) {
            return null;
          }
          var bound = Math.pow(2, zoom);
          return 'http://mw1.google.com/mw-planetary/lunar/lunarmaps_v1/clem_bw' +
              '/' + zoom + '/' + normalizedCoord.x + '/' +
              (bound - normalizedCoord.y - 1) + '.jpg';
      },
      tileSize: new maps.Size(256, 256),
      maxZoom: 9,
      minZoom: 0,
      radius: 1738000,
      name: 'Moon'
    });

    $scope.$watch("map.control", function( mapControl, emptyObj ) {
      mapControl.mapTypes.set('moon', moonMapType);
      mapControl.setMapTypeId('moon');
    });
  }

  // Normalizes the coords that tiles repeat across the x axis (horizontally)
  // like the standard Google map tiles.
  function getNormalizedCoord(coord, zoom) {
    var y = coord.y;
    var x = coord.x;

    // tile range in one direction range is dependent on zoom level
    // 0 = 1 tile, 1 = 2 tiles, 2 = 4 tiles, 3 = 8 tiles, etc
    var tileRange = 1 << zoom;

    // don't repeat across y-axis (vertically)
    if (y < 0 || y >= tileRange) {
      return null;
    }

    // repeat across x-axis
    if (x < 0 || x >= tileRange) {
      x = (x % tileRange + tileRange) % tileRange;
    }

    return {x: x, y: y};
  }
});
```